# I am exporting data to CSV but I want to calculate something then export it

Tags: php, mysql, csv

```
 <?php
```

Database Connection

```
include('db.php');
```

**Fetch Record from Database**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$first_day=$_POST['date_start'];
$last_day=$_POST['date_end'];
$output= "";
$table="users_new_test"; // Enter Your Table Name
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT indx,date_start,id,name,tl_name,skills,grp,shift,breaktime,updatetime FROM $table WHERE date_start >= '$first_day' AND date_end <= '$last_day' ORDER BY date_start ASC");
$columns_total = mysqli_num_fields($sql);
```

Get The Field Name

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$heading = mysqli_field_name($sql, $i);
$output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";

// Get Records from the table

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
}
$output .="\n";
}
```

Download the file

```
$filename =  date("d-m-Y").'.csv';
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $output;
exit;
header("location:export_excel.php");
}   
?>
```

I want to calculate the count of shift on particular date.
Like

```
2016-11-19
Shift = Morning (12)
Shift = Late Morning (12)
Shift = Evening (12)
Shift = Late Evening (12)
Shift = Night (12)

2016-11-20
Shift = Morning (14)
Shift = Late Morning (10)
Shift = Evening (15)
Shift = Late Evening (9)
Shift = Night (12)
```

How can I achieve this. Any Suggestions. Please have a look I am new in development.

Comment: I am down voting because 1) code is horribly indented. 2) you are using mysql_* 3) you haven't given a clear problem statement.

Comment: there is no problem in code, i want to get some additional things i have written that i want to calculate the shifts count.

Comment: google for code indenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TPLMedia24 is right. Use MySQL instead of looping on every line of the result.

```
SELECT date_start, shift, COUNT(*) as total FROM FROM $table WHERE date_start >= '$first_day' AND date_end <= '$last_day' GROUP BY shift, date_start ORDER BY date_start ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to count every field before making CSV file. You can make mysql query and echo results that you liked on a table then make a csv file from it. Inform me if you need additional help regarding this problem. However, you can get an idea from there https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html